multiplication in the ring of formal Laurent series
Let $F$ be a field and define the ring $F((x))$ of formal Laurent series with coefficients from $F$ by
$$
F((x))=\left.\left\{\,\sum_{n\geqslant N}^{\infty}a_nx^n\,\right|\,a_n\in F\text{ and }N\in\mathbb{Z}\,\right\}.
$$
(Every element of $F((x))$ is a power series in $x$ plus a polynomial in $1/x$, i.e., each element of $F((x))$ has only a finite number of terms with negative powers of $x$.)
Let $\sum_{n=N_1}^{\infty}a_nx^n,\sum_{n=N_2}^{\infty}b_nx^n\in F((x))$. Is the following multiplication in $F((x))$ right:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\left(\sum_{n=N_1}^{\infty}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=N_2}^{\infty}b_nx^n\right)
 \\=&\;\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_{N_1+k}b_{N_2+n-k}\right)x^{N_1+N_2+n}?
\end{aligned}
$$


Thanks for @Qiaochu Yuan 's comment, he reminds me that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\left(\sum_{n=N_1}^{\infty}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=N_2}^{\infty}b_nx^n\right)
 \\=&\left(x^{N_1}\sum_{n-N_1=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-N_1}\right)\left(x^{N_2}\sum_{n-N_2=0}^{\infty}b_nx^{n-N_2}\right)
 \\=&\left(x^{N_1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i+N_1}x^i\right)\left(x^{N_2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_{j+N_2}x^{j}\right)
 \\=&\;x^{N_1+N_2}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i+j=m}a_{i+N_1}b_{j+N_2}\right)x^m\right)
 \\=&\;x^{N_1+N_2}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^ma_{i+N_1}b_{(m-i)+N_2}\right)x^m\right)
 \\=&\;\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^ma_{i+N_1}b_{m-i+N_2}\right)x^{m+N_1+N_2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Yes. After multiplying by $x^{-N_1}$ on the first factor and $x^{-N_2}$ on the second factor it just reduces to multiplication of formal power series.

There are infinitely many coefficients. I am not sure even multiplication can be defined.
